# "my first book working with you" - is this acceptable?

Tags: participle-phrases, reference

This is my first book of poetry **working** with you, so I hope this will eventually be the first step to a long partnership.

I got this from my American buddy, but this is weird to me. Is he making a stupid mistake? Or am I stupid?

Comment: What exactly do you find "weird" about the text? There's certainly nothing particularly unusual about the sequence [*my first job working **on** (whatever I worked on in my first job)*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22my+first+job+working+on%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), and I don't see why *... **with** you* should be any different.

Comment: Well, yes - except that using present continuous there is not idiomatic in standard English (only *Indian* English, and I personally would strongly recommend IE speakers to avoid it where possible). A native speaker might say *This is the first time I have worked on a book of poetry with you,* for example.

Comment: Given the text *as it stands*, there are two "natural" interpretations. #1: *I've worked on **other projects** with you, but this is the first time we've worked together on a book of poetry*. #2: *I've worked on books of poetry with **other collaborators**, but this is the first time I've worked on one with **you***. But both you and he will obviously know which meaning applies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not incorrect, and no one would have any difficulty understanding you.

On the other hand, I think it's a little clumsy, and not just because of the bland verb choice "working".  I would say

> This is the first time I have had the opportunity to write a book of poetry with you, but I hope this will eventually be the first step in a long partnership.

This emphasizes

- The act of writing.
- That you saw working with him/her to be an opportunity, and it was something you enjoyed.
- That you don't think that writing a single book together in some way obliges him/her to stay in a long-term partnership with you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing a mistake there. It may be clearer with a different verb there:

> This is my first book **collaborating** with you, so I hope this will eventually be the first step to a long partnership.

"Collaborating" and "working" are interchangable here.

He's just saying that this book was his first time working with you, and that he hopes it is the first step to a long partnership of more collaboration.

Comment: It is a reduced clause ? isn't it ? ".. first book that I am working with you "